# REST API - dispatch events

Tags: magento2, event-observer, rest-api

I have custom module and my code structure is as per **service contact**.

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/AccountManagement.php

Now i have a dispatch event in my model file

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('vendor_register_success', $eventParams);
```

As per REST API standard and as per the this [solution](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/REST-api-dispatch-events/td-p/56744) i added event in specific module where it comes from.

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="vendor_register_success">
        <observer name="vendor_register_success" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\VendorBrandRegister" />
    </event>   
</config>
```

and My observer looks like this

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Observer/VendorBrandRegister.php

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "In execute"; exit;
    }
```

but this event is not dispatching.
What am i missing Because as per the [solution](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/REST-api-dispatch-events/td-p/56744) i need to add events in `webapi_rest` folder in `etc` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for dispatch event.

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('vendor_register_success', [$eventParams]);
```

Instead of

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('vendor_register_success', $eventParams);
```

As second parameter should be an array. This may help you.

Comment: Tried this solution. Not working.

Comment: It's specific webapi_rest related issue.. how to `dispatch event` in that.

Comment: You have done proper, I have seen only difference that I have mentioned. In my opinion First check the code s executed or not?

Comment: No, it's not going in execute function, now i am not magento allows or not dispatch event in model for service contact

Comment: it should allows  to dispatch event as you can check from Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService.php, I think the area webapi_rest may not works for events as for events only three area has been told in magento doc. you can check here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/observers-bp.html

Comment: Yeah, they made and event `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after` but where they dispatching the event

Comment: + for your efforts man !! :)

Comment: here vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by defining `events.xml` in `webapi_rest` folder.

> vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

Magento is doing it in quote module for sending mail.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="sendEmail" instance="Magento\Quote\Observer\Webapi\SubmitObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Reference 1 - From Vinai Kopp: https://twitter.com/VinaiKopp/status/810897855527485440

[**Reference 2**](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/REST-api-dispatch-events/td-p/56744)

Comment: also https://mage2.pro/t/topic/137   vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml